# How to download all blobfiles with a sas url?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

Showing all blobs in a (foreign) container is possible with the code below, so I know the provide SAS-url is valid

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient, BlobServiceClient

sas_url = r'[the sas_token]'
container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_url)
blob_list = container.list_blobs()  
for blob in blob_list:
  print(blob.name)
```

How do I download the contents of the container to a local folder?
With our own containers I would connect with a BlobServiceClient using the provided connection-string, which I don't have for this container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. All you need to do is create [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python) from `ContainerClient` and blob name using [`get_blob_client`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-get-blob-client) method. Once you have that, you will be able to download the blob using [`download_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-download-blob) method.

Your code would be something like:

```
sas_url = r'[the sas_token]'
container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_url)
blob_list = container.list_blobs()  
for blob in blob_list:
  print(blob.name)
  blob = container.get_blob_client(blob.name)
  blob.download_blob();
```

Please ensure that your SAS URL has `Read` permission otherwise download operation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else tries to save csv's from a blob here is the code is used with Gaurav's help

```
sas_url = r'[SAS_URL]'
sas_token = r'[SAS_token]'
container = ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_url)
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="[ACCOUNT NAME]", credential=sas_token)  
blob_list = container.list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
    name = blob.name
    length = len(name)
    nr = length - name.rfind('/') - 1
    filename = name[-nr:]
    if name[-4:] == '.csv':
        try:
            blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(account_url='[CONTAINER]', blob=name)
            blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
            file = blob_data.readall()
            file = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(file))
            file.to_csv(filename)
        except:
            Exception
```